# column reference xxx is ambiguous (candidates: excluded.xxx,table.xxx) in upsert statement

Tags: knex.js, upsert, cockroachdb

I would like to perform upsert sql statement in cockroach DB.

I would like to insert row into table when specific **id** does not exist in table and update **name** column when id with given value exist in table.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS programs_tiers (
  id STRING PRIMARY KEY,
  program_id STRING NOT NULL REFERENCES programs (id),
  name STRING,
  created TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  UNIQUE(program_id, name)
);
```

Here is my sql statement using **knex**.

```
 const response =  await this.knex.raw('INSERT INTO programs_tiers (id,name) values(?,?) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET name = excluded.name  WHERE program_id = ? AND id = ?',[tierId, tierName, programId, tierId]);
```

I'm getting following error:

> error: column reference "id" is ambiguous (candidates: excluded.id,
>   programs_tiers.id).

How could i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the table name to fix the ambiguity:

```sql
[...] WHERE program_id = ? AND programs_tiers.id = ?
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: yes, that was the problem. Thanks! but why when I'm operating on one table ?

Comment: The database creates a "virtual" `excluded` table that contains the inserted values. This table also has an `id` column.